# Convert 'beep' to 'click' sound

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I'm currently using a metronome with a 'beep' sound that I find quite annoying. I prefer the standalone metronome to a phone app but there's no way to change the sound it makes.

Is there some way I could maybe use an op-amp or 555 timer to convert the beep to a click using a small low powered simple device that a newb like me could build?

I've spent ages here and on google searching but not found anything like what I'm looking for. I'd rather use my current metronome as the timing source because it's accurate and easy to set to an exact beat.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There are apps that allow a tick sound. On iOS or windows or Android and very accurate. Can you not find any?

Comment: A "tick" is really just a short "beep". For example, the 1-second ticks you hear when you listen to the WWV time signal are really 10 cycles (10 ms) of a 1000-Hz tone. It's just too short to perceive it as a tone. That said, it seems silly to build hardware to address what is really a software problem in the first place.

Comment: Maybe I explained badly in my original post but this is a stand alone metronome. I'm trying to avoid using a computer based device such as a phone or tablet.

Comment: So, you're expecting recommendations on how to modify a device for which you have no schematic? It will be easier to get a new metronome.

Comment: I'm not looking to modify the metronome. I'm using the output jack to feed a new piece of circuitry with it's own battery. Not very elegant but I'm been unable to find a stand-alone electronic metronome that has a sound that is acceptable to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want a pulse with a width of a few milliseconds. You can start with a circuit to catch the edge of the first few cycles of the beep with fast attack and slow release, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD2YAP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am guessing here at an attack time of about a millisecond, and a release of a few hundred. If the input is big enough and you look with a scope, you want to see a pulse at the output which rises quickly at the start of the pulse and then dies away more slowly.

This probably won't be "clicky" enough, and you will probably have to follow this stage with a 555 or similar monostable, giving an output pulse of around 1-10 mS. Adjust the width will to get a satisfying sound to your ears.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have access to a scope but this gives me a starting point for bread-boarding

Answer (score 0):

Generically, a dual monostable multivibrator with a long pulse triggered off the beginning of the beep and a shorter output pulse triggered off the leading edge of the first one would do it. Something like a 74HC123 with 50ms (?) blanking/trigger pulse and perhaps a 1ms output pulse. It would need a 3~5V supply.

If you apply the input signal to a something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjxll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output can drive a transistor to drive the transducer.

Comment: It doesn't need much volume so I'll try driving the speaker directly from your circuit.

Comment: Direct from 74hc123 you should add a series resistor maybe 100 ohms.